# For Documentation Beta, how do we output results in example?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, stack-snippets, documentation-editor

When creating examples for HTML, CSS, and Javascript topics, I couldn't find an option to use code snippets. Code snippets makes it much more easier to understand, and it's convenient. Plus, people looking at the examples can tinker with the values and learn more from it. Copying code and running it in your own text editor is troublesome.

So is there code snippets, or at least an option to output results? **Or do we use screenshots to do that?**

Comment: If you look at the existing JavaScript topics, you'll see a number of people using "blockquote" markdown for the results. Hopefully I'll be forgiven for pointing to [an example I wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/265/date/1204/comparing-date-values#t=201607211757338109797) as an exmplar.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'll do that if I write any Javascript/jQuery topics. But there's still the markup topics though...